What is the fastest known algorithm for evaluating a homogenous binary polynomial?
Let $f(x,y) = \sum_{i = 0}^d f_i x^i y^{d-i}$ be a homogenous binary polynomial of degree $d \in \mathbb{N}$ over a field $k$. I want to evaluate $f$ at a point $P_0 = (x_0, y_0) \in k^2$. What is the fastest known algorithm (in the number of multiplications in $k$) to do that? It is well-known that the result $f(x_0, 1)$ can be found by means of Horner's scheme with $d$ multiplications in $k$. What about the point $P_0$ with the arbitrary value $y_0$?

An obvious idea would be to compute $f(x_0/y_0,1)$ in $d$ multiplications and $y_0^d$ in $\log d$ multiplications

How about this simple method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250736/5802041 where, in a funny way, horner has become homer... what an odyssey...

If the inverse operation is slow, so is the reduction to the non-homogenous polynomial.

@JeanMarie  Odyssey indeed!  I've just ordered a translation of Aeschylus,  the Agamemnon... there is a moving speech about grief and loss, this was quoted in an American television series.  Actually there is probably a translation online as well, I should check, but I like physical books.

@Will Jagy Yes, coming back to the fundamental references is never bad, especialy in these "stormy times"...

I see several simple ways to compute $f(x,y)$ with $3d$ multiplications in $k$. Is this the optimal solution?

The question was now cross-posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/482276/
